# Using Python for loop to solve an equation with numerical method

Tags: python, algorithm, numerical-methods

I am learning Python and Probabilities.

I have as a given that the expression:

```
c = n! /((n-1)!1!) + 2*n! /((n-2)*2!) + 3*n!/((n-3)*3!) + ...+ n*n!/((n-n)*n!
```

where 0! = 1 and ! signifies 'factorial', i.e. n! = 1*2*3*...*(n-1)*n.
is equal to:

```
(a + n^b)*2^(c*n + d).  (^ signifies exponent)
```

My goal is to determine the parameters a, b, c, d using 'brute force'.

I calculated using the above formula c for n=3 (12), n=4 (38), n=5 (80), n=6 (192), n=7 (448).

Then I expressed the parameters as ratios of two integers: i.e. 
a = a1/a2, b=b1/b2, c=c1/c2, d=d1/d2.

Finally I defined the following function:

```
def com():
    parms = []
    for a1 in range(-10, 10):
        for a2 in range(1,11):
            for b1 in range(-10,10):
                for b2 in range(1, 11):
                    for c1 in range(-10,10):
                        for c2 in range(1, 11):
                            for d1 in range(-10 , 10):
                                for d2 in range(1 , 11):
                                    a = a1/a2
                                    b = b1/b2
                                    c = c1/c2
                                    d = d1/d2
                                    cr1 = ( 12 == (a + 3**b)*2**(c*3+d) )
                                    cr2 = ( 38 == (a + 4**b)*2**(c*4+d) )
                                    cr3 = ( 80 == (a + 5**b)*2**(c*5+d) )
                                    cr4 = ( 192 == (a + 6**b)*2**(c*6+d) )
                                    cr5 = ( 448 == (a + 7**b)*2**(c*7+d) )
                                    criterion = cr1 & cr2 & cr3 & cr4 & cr5
                                    if criterion == 1 :
                                        parms = [a, b, c, d]
                                        break
    return parms
```

However, my function returns an empty list.

Could you explain that?  Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve my objective?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: That nesting is extreme; checkout `itertools`

Comment: What did you try to debug the program? Have you tried printing out a, b, c, d? Are there values of a, b, c, d that produce very close approximations to 12, 38, 80 etc.? Why do you believe there's a solution in this range?

Comment: FYI, your a, b, c and d values are gonna be integers and therefore not containing the values you expect. (If I get what you are doing). You may want to cast them as floats ( `a = float(a1/a2)`)

Comment: @bouletta not sure if I have understood your point correctly but note that in Python 2, `a = float(a1/a2)` gives `0.0` if, for example, `a1=1` and `a2=2`. Not sure which version OP is using but if you wanted that to be a float you'd need `a = float(a1)/a2`

Comment: @roganjosh You are completely correct. I wrote too quickly! Your version is of course what I meant.

Comment: @MYGz for me personally, I had never seen that before and only guessed that it was a session.

Comment: Caution, cr2 = 32 !

Answer (score 1):

#### Firstly, let's look at some bugs in your code:

```
criterion = cr1 & cr2 & cr3 & cr4 & cr5
```

This is performing `bitwise` operations on the values. You probably wanted:

```
criterion = cr1 and cr2 and cr3 and cr4 and cr5
```

Python also provides an `all` function, which you could check if `all` things are `True`:

```
criterion = all([cr1,cr2,cr3,cr4,cr5])
```

#### Now, let's look at your `if` statement:

```
if criterion == 1 :
```

Since you want to know if `criterion` is `True` or `False`, you can simply use `if criterion:`.

#### Now lastly, this approach is unlikely to ever be `True`. Take this line for example:

```
cr1 = ( 12 == (a + 3**b)*2**(c*3+d) )
```

Those numbers would have to add up to exactly 12, else it will be `False`, and then you will get an empty list.

### Also, [computers can't do decimal maths accurately](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-do-computers-suck-at-math/).

To solve the actual values, you must use parameter substitution. That's not a programming question, but maths and programming go together well, so here's a starter:

```
12 = (a + 3**b)*2**(c*3+d)
12/(a+3**b) = 2**(c*3+d)
```

... and so on. Get `a` in terms of `b`, `c`,and `d`, then use your `cr2` to substitute in `a` for the numbers you have, and get `b` in terms of `c` and `d`.

Repeat a few more times, and you have numbers for the four values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy curvefit` and use non-linear least squares to fit a function, f, to data and find the parameters (a,b,c,d) values. The example data that you provided fit to the function `(a + n**b)+2**(c*n + d)` better. Notice that best fit for the values of `a,b,c,d` are floating point numbers, not integers.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata = np.array(range(3,8))
ydata = np.array([12,38,80,192,448])

def func(n, a, b, c, d):
  return (a + n**b)+2**(c*n + d)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=(1,1,1,1))
a, b, c, d = popt
print a, b, c, d # learnt parameters
# -5.62374782967 1.79345876905 1.29232902743 -0.328778229316

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, a, b, c, d), '-r', label='np.poly')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In the above fitted curve, blue points are the data points and red line is the fitted function with the learnt parameters, notice that the function is continuous and defined for all values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

With brains instead of Python:

You recognize a modified Binomial sum, `Sum k.Cnk` instead of `Sum Cnk`.

Then notice that

```
k.n!/(k!(n-k)!) = n!/((k-1)!(n-k)!) = n.(n-1)!/(k-1)!(n-1-k+1)!) = n.Cn-1,k+1.
```

So your sum will be `n.2^(n-1)`.

Comment: Okay, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Before rushing into brute force, it may be wiser to attempt to estimate a tight range for the parameters.

The first values of the sum are

```
1, 4, 12, 32, 80, 192, 448, 1024, 2304, 5120, 11264
```

Taking the pairwise ratios, you observe that they get closer and closer to 2.

As the ratio `(a + (n+1)^b)/(a + n^b)` will tend to 1 and the ratio `2^(c(n+1)+d)/2^(cn+d)` will tend to `2^c`, you are hinted that `c` is probably close to 1. You can check this estimate by trying larger and larger values of `n` (For instance, `n=1000` yields the ratio `2.002002... = 2^1.00144...`).

Then to reduce the growth rate of the expression to make it more tractable, it can be interesting to look at the values of `Sum/2^n`, and we get

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

Hum, hum.

---

Unfortunately, this case is too easy for a proper demonstration of the method. The general idea is to observe the asymptotic behavior to get a rough estimate of some of the parameters. And when you have such a rough estimate (in a small range), then you can somehow cancel its effect to better see the effect of the other ones.

For exhaustive searches, understanding the ranges is important.